# Automount lost (moved?) files from my /data folder

Tags: ubuntu, automount

I copied some things to the /data folder on my ubuntu 10.04. After restarting all the data was gone. After some investigation I figured out that automount was using the /data folder (it appeared in lsof | grep /data and /etc/auto.master contains /data entry ), which I completely forgot about. Now, I have two questions:

1) Is there a way to recover my data or has automount deleted it?

2) df -h tells me that my / partition has 1.3 GB free while I am sure it had 3 GB before I copied the stuff to my /data folder, and the "missing" 1.7 GB seems exactly right for the size of my copied stuff. Where would this data be moved to (i.e. this would answer 1) and how do I get my 1.7 GB back?

Thanks

EDIT:

my /etc/auto.master

```
/data           yp:auto.data
/homes          yp:auto.homes
/projects       yp:auto.projects
/services       yp:auto.services
/users          yp:auto.users
```

my /etc/fstab

```
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
UUID=21f6ee12-734a-4d3f-a23a-079c2a5381c6 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=50b83a82-f894-409e-939d-1908ca8aacf1 /boot           ext3    defaults        0       2
UUID=afac7a83-2fc4-410a-a2ea-06f3eb7ce0d5 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
UUID=4a5ae91c-89fb-4d3e-ba51-81896d61dae3 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: Your data should be fine. Please post the contents of your `/etc/fstab`, manually mounting the partition should work. If you also post your `/etc/auto.master` file, I should be able to help you get it setup correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the automount service is mounting a folder from your NIS (hence the `yp:`) to `/data`. If you copied your files to `/data` while the `autofs` service was running, then your files are now on whatever server was exporting to `/data`.

If the service was **not** active when you copied and it **is** now, then your files will not be visible as `/data` now points to a remote folder. So, stop the `autofs` service:

```
sudo service autofs stop
```

Check if your data is there:

```
ls /data
```

If it is and everything is in order, change your `auto.master` file to NOT use your `/data` folder then restart the autofs service:

```
sudo service autofs restart
```

Comment: Thanks.. I was sure I tried this first, but I must have screwed it up. It does work now and my stuff is indeed intact in /data (the remote server was not connected at any point)